# Cannot login, and i getting POST http://localhost:5000/auth/login 404 (Not Found) and net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, cookies, getstream-chat

I have been trying to login and I get POST http://localhost:5000/auth/login 404 (Not Found) with url set to **http://** and I get net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR with **https:/ /** I can register a user normally but the login throws an error.

This is the Auth.jsx for login and singnup:

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, phoneNumber, avatarURL } = form;

        const URL = 'https://localhost:5000/auth';

        const { data: { token, userId, hashedPassword } } = await axios.post(`${URL}/${isSignup ? 'signup' : 'login'}`, {
            username, password, fullName, phoneNumber, avatarURL,
        });

        cookies.set('token', token);
        cookies.set('username', username);
        cookies.set('fullName', fullName);
        cookies.set('userId', userId);

        if(isSignup) {
            cookies.set('phoneNumber', phoneNumber);
            cookies.set('avatarURL', avatarURL);
            cookies.set('hashedPassword', hashedPassword);
        }

        window.location.reload();
    
    }
```

when logout i remove the cookies:

```js
const ChannelListContainer = () => {

    const logout = () => {
        cookies.remove("token");
        cookies.remove('userId');
        cookies.remove('username');
        cookies.remove('fullName');
        cookies.remove('avatarURL');
        cookies.remove('hashedPassword');
        cookies.remove('phoneNumber');

        window.location.reload();
    }
```

This is the auth.js backend:

```js
const { connect } = require('getstream');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const StreamChat = require('stream-chat').StreamChat;
const crypto = require('crypto');

require('dotenv').config();

const api_key = process.env.STREAM_API_KEY;
const api_secret = process.env.STREAM_API_SECRET;
const app_id = process.env.STREAM_APP_ID;

const signup = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { fullName, username, password, phoneNumber } = req.body

        const userId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

        const serverClient = connect(api_key, api_secret, app_id);

        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

        const token = serverClient.createUserToken(userId);

        res.status(200).json({ token, fullName, username, userId, hashedPassword, phoneNumber})

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

        res.status(500).json({ message: error })
    }
};

const login = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { username, password } = req.body;

        const serverClient = connect(api_key, api_secret, app_id);

        const client = StreamChat.getInstance(api_key, api_secret);

        const { users } = await client.queryUsers({ name: username });

        if(!users.length) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Usuario no encontrado' });

        const success = await bcrypt.compare(password, users[0].hashedPassword);

        const token = serverClient.createUserToken(users[0].id);

        if(success) {
            res.status(200).json({ token, fullName: users[0].fullName, username, userId: users[0].id });

        } else {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Contraseña incorrecta' });
        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)

        res.status(500).json({ message: error })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem will be caused by the fact, that you are using `https` protocol on your localhost. Unless you have a server running on your local machine that serves the content via `https`, you should use `http`.

So instead of this:
`const URL = 'https://localhost:5000/auth';`

Try this:
`const URL = 'http://localhost:5000/auth';`

I hope this helps :)